# WebView: accessing JavaScriptInterface from multiple pages

Tags: android, webview

In a WebView, how do you access the JavaScriptInterface from multiple web 
pages, and not just from the page that you load via mWebView.loadUrl(…)

e.g.

In my project's assets folder, I have:

```
index.html
page1.html
page2.html
```

... and here is the relevant WebView code:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

So at different points in time, a user may look at index.html, page1.html, etc. From what I can tell, only the JavaScript in index.html has access to the JavaScriptInterface via "window.android.someMethodName()". When I try to make a call to "window.android.someMethodName()" from page1.html, it says that "window.android" is not defined.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "access from multiple web pages" ? Can you drop some code ?

Comment: I have added some more details to the original post.